# Maven Release Plugin Issue - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

Struggling to maven:release this project.  Looks like a version incompatibility issue, but I'm not sure how to rectify this issue.  I'm using Maven version 3.1.1.

Here's my pom.xml (sample)

```
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>index</report>
              <report>summary</report>
              <report>project-team</report>
              <report>mailing-list</report>
              <report>cim</report>
              <report>issue-tracking</report>
              <report>scm</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

Here's the maven stack trace during release:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) on project project-common-root: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.maven.scm.command.tag.AbstractTagCommand.executeTagCommand(Lorg/apache/maven/scm/provider/ScmProviderRepository;Lorg/apache/maven/scm/ScmFileSet;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/maven/scm/ScmTagParameters;)Lorg/apache/maven/scm/ScmResult;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-gitexe/1.1/maven-scm-provider-gitexe-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/regexp/regexp/1.3/regexp-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-git-commons/1.1/maven-scm-provider-git-commons-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.7/plexus-utils-1.5.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/release/maven-release-manager/2.3.2/maven-release-manager-2.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-6/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-6.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-invoker/2.0.9/maven-invoker-2.0.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0/commons-logging-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-providers-standard/1.7/maven-scm-providers-standard-1.7.pom
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-accurev/1.7/maven-scm-provider-accurev-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-bazaar/1.7/maven-scm-provider-bazaar-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-clearcase/1.7/maven-scm-provider-clearcase-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-cvsexe/1.7/maven-scm-provider-cvsexe-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-cvs-commons/1.7/maven-scm-provider-cvs-commons-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-cvsjava/1.7/maven-scm-provider-cvsjava-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/netbeans/lib/cvsclient/20060125/cvsclient-20060125.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/ch/ethz/ganymed/ganymed-ssh2/build210/ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-hg/1.7/maven-scm-provider-hg-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-perforce/1.7/maven-scm-provider-perforce-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-starteam/1.7/maven-scm-provider-starteam-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-svnexe/1.7/maven-scm-provider-svnexe-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-synergy/1.7/maven-scm-provider-synergy-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-vss/1.7/maven-scm-provider-vss-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-tfs/1.7/maven-scm-provider-tfs-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-integrity/1.7/maven-scm-provider-integrity-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/com/mks/api/mksapi-jar/4.10.9049/mksapi-jar-4.10.9049.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/1.7.6/groovy-all-1.7.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-jazz/1.7/maven-scm-provider-jazz-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-manager-plexus/1.7/maven-scm-manager-plexus-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-svn-commons/1.7/maven-scm-provider-svn-commons-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/jaxen/jaxen/1.1-beta-8/jaxen-1.1-beta-8.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/jdom/jdom/1.0/jdom-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.5.6/slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.6/slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.5.6/jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.2.1/maven-reporting-api-2.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.1/doxia-sink-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.1/doxia-logging-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-api/1.7/maven-scm-api-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[47] = file:/Users/161541/.m2/repository/org/jdom/jdom/1.1/jdom-1.1.jar
```

Comment: If you are using Maven 3.1.X you shouldn't use such old plugins like maven-compiler-plugin (current: 3.1), maven-release-plugin (current:2.4.2) and so on. After updating the plugins (using pluginManagement) you should retry this. Apart from that how exactly did you call Maven? Can you show the full pom you are using? Have you called Maven from command line?

Comment: Add at least a version to the maven-project-info-reports-plugin. Here are some compatibility links: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Plugin+Compatibility+Matrix and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*SOLVED* After upgrading the plugins to the latest releases, the project still failed to be built with the same error.  It was actually a mistake in the root pom.xml.

Turns out the root was the presence of a "< scm >" tag in one of the pom.xml files.

Removing the following tag allowed the maven release:perform task to be run:

```
REMOVED:

<scm>
    <tag>itabuy-common-root-2.06</tag>
</scm>
```

Thank you khmarbaise and Robert Scholte for your help.

Comment: How did removing this help? How could this be causing the error? I have the same error and a similar `scm` tag. However, if I comment out the tag, the error doesn't disappear.

Comment: It would have worked from him while running `mvn release:prepare` hence the answer but next step in which we release would have failed again, is what I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was updating `org.apache.maven.scm` plugin from `1.9` to `2.0.1`

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```